# Why does simp "fail to apply initial proof method" where blast succeeds with the same facts?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I have modelled [this calculus](http://www.appliedlogictudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/S-Frittella_G-Greco_A-Kurz_A-Palmigiano_V-Sikimic_Multi-type-Display-Calculus-for-Dynamic-Epistemic-Logic_Applied-Logic-TU-Delft.pdf) in Isabelle as an exercise. [Here's my code so far.](https://github.com/NikolasTzimoulis/MultitypeDEL)

I use sledgehammer to prove simple theorems which usually suggests to use blast supplemented with a subset of the rules of the calculus, e.g.:

```
by (blast intro: DH_bdiam2_f Fbox2_R l2)
```

That works fine and dandy, however if I try to use simp adding the same rules, e.g.:

```
by (simp only: DH_bdiam2_f Fbox2_R l2)
```

I get an error that none of the rules were applicable

```
Failed to apply initial proof method⌂:
```

What is going on exactly? I was expecting that simp either terminates or times out, but certainly not this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the error message you get when a tactic failed to produce a proof step. For `simp`, that's the case when no rule matches (i.e. rewriting with neither `DH_bdiam2_f` ... is impossible). Looking at your code, these rules come from an inductive predicate. Usually, those are not suitable as rewriting (= simplification) rules. Scattered throughout [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016/doc/prog-prove.pdf), there are hints about what are suitable *simplification* and *introduction* rules, along with explanations about what tactics are suitable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think it's possible to edit my theory to make it easier for simp to work with or should I give up on simp and focus on other tactics? The reason I care about simp so much in the first place is because it's the only one that provides a human-readable proof trace.

Comment: I think you should embrace the other tools. To achieve human-readable proofs, I suggest using (structured) Isar proofs.

Comment: I tried using sledgehammer's experimental isar proof mode and it's producing interesting results. Any further advice is welcome.

Comment: You can write Isar proofs by hand. If you want something human-readable, you can't really use automated tools to generate it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's appreciated.